# How to create alias for ssh command?

Tags: ssh, alias

I have a command, which looks like so:

```
$ ssh [long list of parameters, eventually I connect to internalhost]
```

My task is to replace this long list of parameters with just `internalhost`, so that I could run it like so

```
$ ssh internalhost
```

How can I do that?

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: I tried `$ internalhost = long list of parameters`, but in this case, I have to run it like `$ ssh $internalhost`. But it is not what I must get.

Comment: @steeldriver. Thank you, sir! I will check it.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Standard SSH clients read the configuration files before any connection:

```
/etc/ssh/ssh_config   # system-wide
~/.ssh/config         # per user
```

with the latter having more priority.
Ideally, you want to configure the systemwide config with parameters that please all users and the config in your homedir with options specific to you.
Here's an example of `~/.ssh/config`

```
Host remote.example.com
    User            dev1
    IdentityFIle    ~/.ssh/id_rsa_remote
```

Then to connect:

```
ssh remote.example.com
```

> **Note**: `~/.ssh/config` must have read/write permissions for the user, and not be accessible by others (`chmod 600 ~/.ssh/config`)

All possible options are documented in ssh_config manual pages: [man ssh_config](https://man.openbsd.org/ssh_config)

Answer (score 18):

I usually use the `.ssh/config` file found in my home directory to run my OpenSSH client in the format `ssh ubserver`. In that file found here `/home/$USER/.ssh` I have the follow configurations:

```
Host ubserver
    Hostname 127.0.0.1
    Port 2222
    User george
```

Meaning I can simply do:

```
ssh ubserver
```

and connect to the said server without typing more than that line in the terminal.